# Where to get Azure Pipeline AppCenterDistribute@3 Task destinationStoreId?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center

I'm creating an automatic distribution in our Azure DevOps pipeline to our AppCenter to automatic publish to the Google play store.

The automatic distribution in our pipeline to a AppCenter Group works fine like this:

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenter'
    appSlug: 'mycompany/appname'
    appFile: '**/android/bin/nl.mycompany.appname.apk'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'some comment'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: '813c4695-5f9c-4b10-973e-7awdcsd6'
```

But I can't get to distribution to the Store (through AppCenter) working with this:

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenter'
    appSlug: 'mycompany/appname'
    appFile: '**/android/bin/nl.mycompany.appname.apk'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'some comment'
    destinationType: 'store'
    destinationStoreId: 'Alpha'
```

This returns:

> Error: Distribution Store with id Alpha does not exist.

Any idea where to find `destinationStoreId` in AppCenter or somewhere else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy#setting-up-distribution-with-app-center):

Obtain the Store connection ID using an API call; learn [how to use the App Center API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/index) elsewhere in the documentation.

Call the API using the following link: `https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/stores_list` for querying for the Store IDs using . Below is an example of the results returned from the API call. You will be using the value of the key ID for specifying a store as target.

```
[
  {"id":"ebb146bc-b0d7-4500-9791-fc02f191bff9",
  "name":"Alpha team",
  "type":"apple",
  "track":"testflight-external",
  "created_by":"5114c905-76db-49e5-8a47-58c34b33a38b",
  "service_connection_id":"2a85ad1e-b44e-d6fd-a85f-8daee62b54ed"},
  {"id":"10ba5942-1388-4b2a-869a-9de40d5c0cff",
  "name":"Production",
  "type":"apple",
  "track":"production",
  "created_by":"5114c905-76db-49e5-8a47-58c34b33a38b",
  "service_connection_id":"2a85ad1e-b44e-d6fd-a85f-8daee62b54ed"},
  {"id":"894dd821-9f16-44a3-b2a7-d513d226babb",
  "name":"iTunes Connect users",
  "type":"apple",
  "track":"testflight-internal",
  "created_by":"5114c905-76db-49e5-8a47-58c34b33a38b",
  "service_connection_id":"2a85ad1e-b44e-d6fd-a85f-8daee62b54ed"}
]
```

Check also those GitHub issues:

https://github.com/microsoftdocs/vsts-docs/issues/5128

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3997

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10158

Comment: Whoa, documented but hard to spot. Thanks!

Comment: The `distribute/stores_list` only points to the documentation. To use the API, call `https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/distribution_stores` with your api token set in the header.

Comment: also note if you check the network calls when getting the list of stores from within AppCenter, you can see the IDs